# Как подключиться к MySQL через java?

Tags: java, mysql

Как подключится к `MySQL` через `java`? И как сделать добавление запроса?

Comment: Читайте про JDBC

Answer (score 2):

Как вам верно посоветовали выше — JDBC. В случае с MySQL — [официальный JDBC драйвер](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Там же найдёте и документацию.

Answer (score 0):

Написано понятным языком:

[Подключение к `MySQL` с помощью `Jdbc`](http://j2w.blogspot.com/2008/01/mysql-jdbc.html)